# Plotting color coded markers in matplotlib-basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have the following variables, that I want to plot on a map:
 `Lons`, a list of longitudes, `Lats`, a list of latitudes and `Vals`, a list of values for each location.

To plot the locations, I do a simple

```
x,y=Mymap(Lons,Lats)
Mymap.scatter(x,y,marker='o',color='red')
```

**Q:** how do i best turn my `Vals` into a list of colors (heatmap) to be passed into`scatter`, so that every `x,y` pair gets its values matching color?

The basemap docs are rather lacking, and none of the examples fits my purposes.

I could probably loop through my whole `Lats`, `Lons` and `Vals` but given how slow basemap is, I'd rather avoid that. I already have to draw about 800 maps, and increasing that to about 1 Million will probably take years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [basemap scatter documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.scatter) simply refers to the [pyplot.scatter documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), where you can find the parameter **c** (emphasis mine):

> **c** : color or sequence of color, optional, default
>
> **c** can be a single color format string, or a sequence of color specifications of length N, **or a sequence of N numbers to be mapped to colors** using the cmap and norm specified via kwargs (see below). Note that c should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. c can be a 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA, however.

So if you simply pass `vals` to c, matplotlib should convert the values to colors on the standard colormap or a [chosen colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). To show which color is mapped to what value you can use the [colorbar](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar).

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lons = range(50)
lats = range(25, 75)
vals = range(50,100)

plt.scatter(lons, lats, c=vals, cmap='afmhot')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was only looking round in the main documentation, since i thought the api part was internal stuff, only useful when you want to really change stuff under the hood.