# Coloring points based on a variable value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, cartopy

I have a dataset of temperature values at a network of weather stations. I am looking to plot the data on a map, with the points colored based on the temperature at that station. Is there such capability found in Python/Matplotlib to do this?

For reference: My dataset is in a netCDF file and contains lat/lon values of each station. The temperature variable is a function of station and time. So far, I have plotted the points on a map using Cartopy, but with one color for each point.

Comment: look into the `seaborn` package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting color coded markers in matplotlib-basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146662/plotting-color-coded-markers-in-matplotlib-basemap)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `scatter` plotting command, using the `c` argument:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lon = np.random.rand(50) * 50 - 120
lat = np.random.rand(50) * 25 + 25
temps = np.random.randn(50) * 10 + 25

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.LambertConformal())
ax.scatter(lon, lat, c=temps, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
```